# Dar clic en un Chart Control en ASP:NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

Tengo definido un `Chart` que se llama `chart11` y le doy datos de la siguiente manera utilizando el `load` propio del control

```
protected void Chart11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<byte[]> Datos11 = new List<byte[]>();
    List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
    Datos11 = selectAlarmas1(id);
    foreach (byte[] Datos in Datos11)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
        {
            graficoY.Add(Datos[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.Write("\n");

    foreach (int i in graficoY)
    {
        Console.Write("Y" + i + " ");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < graficoY.Count; i++)
    {
        Chart11.Series["Senales"].Points.AddY(graficoY[i]);
    }

    Chart11.Series["Senales"].PostBackValue = GetPostBackEventReference( Chart11_Click);
    Chart11.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    Chart11.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
}
```

Quiero que al dar clic en ese `Chart` pero no se dispara el evento:

```
protected void Chart11_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
{
    Grafica_Chart(10);
}
```

Quisiera saber cómo hacer para que funcione el evento.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas verificar que tenga la propiedad `autopostback="true"` y manipular las propiedades en las series XValueMember  YValueMember asignandole el valor que necesitas pasar y PostBackValue cual es el valor de estos requerido. Digamos:

```
<asp:Series Name="Miserie" XValueMember="TuValorODato" PostBackValue="#VALX" >
```

Mas claro pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

Primero debes de agregar a tu chart el evento onClick:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="287px" OnClick="Chart1_Click" OnLoad="Chart1_Load" Width="857px">
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Luego en tu code behind

```
    protected void Chart1_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text ="El valor es:"+e.PostBackValue.ToString();
    }

    protected void Chart1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int contador = 1;
        Chart1.Series.Add("Senales");
        while (contador < 10)
        {
            DataPoint punto = new DataPoint(contador,contador);
            Chart1.Series["Senales"].Points.Add(
            contador++;
        }
        Chart1.Series["Senales"].PostBackValue = "#VALX";
    }
```

El evento va ligado al control no a la serie como lo tienes en tu código, en el campo PostBackValue debe ir el elemento que quieres recibir al hacer postback el valor x de la columna(XVAL) o el valor y (YVAL). Copia tal cual este ejemplo en tu código para que lo veas mejor es funcional.

Adicionalmente te sugeriria que le echaras un vistazo a [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/) solo que necesitas aprender conceptos basicos de javascript JSON y jQuery pero es una herramienta mas poderosa que la que nos ofrece default Microsoft VS y .NET

Comment: Igual podria ser  `PostBackValue="#VALY"` si quieres pasar YValueMember

Comment: Robert no entiendo tu respuesta

Comment: Permiteme envio un ejemplo

Comment: bueno creo que con eso entenderia mejor gracias :D

Comment: Por nada, tambien hago otra pequeña edición saco `Chart1.Series["Senales"].PostBackValue = "#VALX";` del loop estoy trabajando en otras cosas y lo hice a las carreras